# jwilder/nginx-proxy: Where is the network configured? (Not in docker-compose.yml)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am new to Docker and found one thing I don't understand: I downloaded the image `jwilder/nginx-proxy` from the Github repo [nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) and ran it with `docker-compose up`. This will bring on a new network `nginxproxy_default`, which the new container is connected to, although the docker-compose.yml does not have a network specified. I searched all files in the repository but I didn't find any place where this network is configured, so where does it come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a default network created automatically by docker-compose. Read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).